# Locate first index at which value exists

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to follow these instructions:

"Write a function called indexOf, which accepts an array and a number.

The function should return the first index at which the value exists or -1 if the value is not found.

Do not use the built in Array.indexOf() function!"

Here is what I have:

```js
function indexOf(arr, number) {
  var panda = arr.indexOf(number) || -1;
  if(typeof(arr) == "object"){
            return arr.indexOf(number);
        } else {
          return -1;
}
}
console.log(
  indexOf([1, 2, 3, 4], 7),
  indexOf([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
  );
```

I am working through some problems on repl.it, so my output in the console is correct, but I am still failing the test cases on repl.it. Could someone help me work through what I am doing wrong? I have gone about this a couple of different ways, but I am not sure using typeof is the best way to evaluate whether or not a given number actually exists in an array, but at the same time and confused on how to evaluate if it exists without using the Array.indexOf function.

Comment: "*Do not use the built in Array.indexOf() function*" seems you're ignoring this requirement

Comment: @VLAZ what would be a good work around?

Comment: If you can't use `Array.indexOf()` then can you use other methods of an array?

Comment: @CodyWirth well, as per the requirement that's *your* job to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `.indexOf()`, so I'm assuming you can use `.findIndex()`?

```js
function indexOf(arr, number) {
  return arr.findIndex(n => n === number);
}
console.log(
  indexOf([1, 2, 3, 4], 7),
  indexOf([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
);
```

Comment: can you clarify what 'n => n' does?

Comment: @CodyWirth It's `n => n === number` - equivalent to the normal function `function(n) { return n === number; }` so, if the element from the array `n` is equal to the `number` supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through and check for the first match, exit the function immediately returning the match.

```js
function indexOf(arr, number) {

  for(let idx=0; idx<arr.length; idx++) {
    if( arr[idx] === number )
       return idx;
  }

  return -1;
}
console.log(
  indexOf([1, 2, 3, 4], 7),
  indexOf([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
  );
```

Comment: Recommended to describe your answer a little in plain English.