# Attempting to return last index of n inside array

Tags: javascript

Here are the instructions that I am working through:

"Write a function called lastIndexOf, which accepts an array and a number.

The function should return the last index at which the value exists, or -1 if the value is not found.

Do not use the built in Array.lastIndexOf() function!"

Here is the code that I have so far:

```js
function lastIndexOf(arr, number) {
  
}
console.log(
  lastIndexOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4], 4),
  lastIndexOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3], 1)
);
```

What function could I use instead of Array.lastIndexOf()? What would something like that look like?

Comment: do you know loops?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `Array.indexOf()`?

Comment: The point of the exercise is to not use built-in functions at all. You'll need to loop over the array elements and do some manual checking.

Comment: The approach should be similar to [the previous time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59513503/locate-first-index-at-which-value-exists) but going in reverse.

Comment: This looks like your homework. In order to learn something you have to do it yourself. It is an exercise. Think! How would you find it without using any function at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [so] is not a coding service. Put some effort into finding the solution and ask on [so] only if you get stuck. Don't forget to post **your** code.

Comment: @VLAZ exactly, I attempted reversing it but have been unsuccessful. Just have to put some more time into I suppose.

Comment: @axiac it is actually not homework seeing as how I finished undergrad about 6 years ago, I am just working through some exercises. I have the function to find the first index, I was just unsure how to reverse it which is why I left the function empty.

Comment: @NinaScholz just the basics, in my head I know you would loop through an array or use recursion, but I am still learning the basics of js

Comment: Homework or not, you are supposed to write some code. Otherwise hire somebody to write it for you (in this case you probably don't have any reason to be on this site any more).

Comment: Write a loop that iterates over the array from the end toward its start. Return from the function when the desired item is found (return its index). Return `-1` after the loop (the item was not found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Iterate through the array, from at the last element index (`arr.length - 1`) to the first (`0`).
- as soon as you find `number`, return the current index
- else return `-1`

```js
function lastIndexOf(arr, number) {
  for(let i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--) if(arr[i] === number) return i;
  return -1;
}

console.log(
  lastIndexOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4], 4),
  lastIndexOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3], 1)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a variable for the index and iterate from the end of the array. If the wanted value is found, return the index.

```js
function lastIndexOf(array, number) {
    var index = array.length;
    while (index--) if (array[index] === number) return index;
    return -1;
}

console.log(lastIndexOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4], 4)); //  5
console.log(lastIndexOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3], 1)); //  4
console.log(lastIndexOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3], 0)); // -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.indexOf` but in `.reverse()`!

```js
function lastIndexOf(arr, number) {
  var a = [...arr]; //separate variable not to change arr
  return arr.length - a.reverse().indexOf(number) - 1;
}
console.log(
  lastIndexOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4], 4),
  lastIndexOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3], 1)
);
```

Comment: I see two opportunities for optimization: duplicating `arr` is expensive, and so is `reverse`. I would suggest saving the time these operations by iterating through `arr` from end to start, returning as soon as one element equals `number`.

Answer (score 0):

edit: You also need to check for i in the while loop in case the value does not exist in the array.

Here's how I did it. Iterate in reverse and !lastIndex catches the first value and returns.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5];

function lastIndexOf(array, value){
    var lastIndex, i=array.length-1;
    while(!lastIndex && (i+1)){lastIndex = array[i]==value? i: lastIndex; i--;}
    return lastIndex;
};

console.log(lastIndexOf(array, 5));
console.log(lastIndexOf(array, 8));
```